# React with redux new window and media query

Tags: reactjs, redux, media-queries, new-window

I use react with redux.
In one of my components I open new window by:

```
 import { store } from "index"

 this.detachedWindow = window.open();
 this.detachedWindow.store = store;
```

So I have two windows open with same store. The problem is when I open new window and then close it. Then I change my url location in old window then there is media query problem like:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addListener' of null 
>      
>    at new r (MediaQuery.js:23)
>      
>    at register (MediaQueryDispatch.js:42)
>      
>    at row.js:105
>      
>    at Array.map ()
>      
>    at t.value (row.js:104)
>      
>    at commitLifeCycles (react-dom.production.min.js:169)
>      
>    at n (react-dom.production.min.js:180)
>      
>    at c (react-dom.production.min.js:183)
>      
>    at l (react-dom.production.min.js:184)
>      
>    at p (react-dom.production.min.js:188)

It only exists when I open and then close new window. What can be reason of it?

Comment: Not sure if a redux store can be "transferred" with a simple assignment like that. There might be more bootstrap/setup code required to initialize it properly in a new window context.

Comment: You have to elaborate more on that. Anyways, if you are doing an `addListener` in, say, `componentDidMount`, you can do a `removeListener` in `componentWillUnmount` and see if it works.